# Install Second logon in Windows Embedded

Tags: windows, embedded, impersonation

just got a couple of new PanelPC's running Windows Embedded 2009 that we are going to send out to clients.

Before we send them we install our software on them and now found out that the service "Second Logon" isn't in the Windows Embedded installation that is on the PC's.

We don't have the possibillity to change the Windows Embedded image ourselvse and are now trying to find out if we can install "Second Logon" somehow?

Does anybody know anything about this.

Comment: After some communication on the microsoft forums it turned out there were no good way to add Second logon afterwards. The only way to go is to request a new image from the manufacturer which turned out to be quite easy, so now we are up and running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some communication on the microsoft forums it turned out there were no good way to add Second logon afterwards. The only way to go is to request a new image from the manufacturer which turned out to be quite easy, so now we are up and running.